# Regular expression supporting multiple spaces using python

Tags: python, regex

I have a sample data as below:

```
(1) fshfonlpjspfmnfmnsjoide                    (2)dfljslmnljoifsjdjmfdsjf
foslndlknjhoihfodsiolnlnlkdfshoipfjhndfs  subsection (3):wdjoinfeiu
(3)fwshfnlfgnoiuhwsoiuheoklnfsojoihoisnf
          (i)fdfssd
          (ii)flshf
   (4)fjdspfj;mf;jspiojepjasm;lfmsdjipoj
```

For the above sample, I want to break the data at each point where I receive paragraph starting numbers e.g (1), (2), (3) etc. pattern

But I dont want to break at points like subsection(3) which is not an actual new paragraph.

I used a regex:  `pattern_string = "(\n|\s\s\s\s\s\s\s)\(\d+\)"`

It works fine when a new paragraph starts in a new line like (1) but doesnt work in case when paragraph doesn't start from new line e.g. (2) in sample above.
or if there is a single space before the pattern in new line e.g. (4) has a single space before it.

Comment: It's not clear what is the difference between a "section" and a "subsection"

Comment: Hi Alfasin,sections are represented by (1), (2), (3), (4) etc. Subsection is just some written text within a section. 

My purpose is to break the whole text at section level. But, each section number doesn't have a fixed starting point. e.g. (1) start at the beginning of a new line. (2) start in the middle of a line and has a white space comprising multiple spaces.

(4) starts from a new line but has some spaces before it.

To cover up the new line, I used \n and also used multiple \s to cover up multiple spaces before (2). For (4), it doesn't work as it has a space before it in a new line.

Comment: If you could use a more readable text, you could receive more help. Try not smashing the keyboard that much

Comment: Hi.
Sure.

(1) my name is xyz\n
      (i) I work at pqr...........(2) My age is xx   subsection(2):abcd\n
...(3)hello there..

I hope this helps. I want separate data for (1), (2), (3) as below:

(1) my name is xyz\n
      (i) I work at pqr...........
(2) My age is xx   subsection(2):abcd
(3)hello there.

Dots represent spaces. e.g. between pqr and (2) there are multiple spaces.

Answer (score 0):

Try using repetitions (also it is good practice to have raw (`r'...'`) strings for regex:

```
r"(^|\n\s*|\s{7,})\((\d+)\)"
```

This should match numbers at

1. Start of the string: `^`
2. New lines even if there are spaces: `\n\s*`
3. After a few spaces (at least 7): `\s{7,}`

Example:

```
>>> re.split(r"(?:^|\n\s*|\s{7,})\(\d+\)", your_text)

['',
 ' fshfonlpjspfmnfmnsjoide',
 'dfljslmnljoifsjdjmfdsjf\nfoslndlknjhoihfodsiolnlnlkdfshoipfjhndfs  subsection (3):wdjoinfeiu',
 'fwshfnlfgnoiuhwsoiuheoklnfsojoihoisnf\n          (i)fdfssd\n          (ii)flshf',
 'fjdspfj;mf;jspiojepjasm;lfmsdjipoj']
```

Just remove the first empty string and you've got all your 4 sections

Comment: Hi,Thankyou for the response. I used the example pattern you just shared. But, it doesnt work for \n\s* and \s{7,}.

So, if a section starts at a new line but has few spaces at the start e.g.
...(2) or it starts in the middle of a line and has multiple spaces before it e.g. abcdpqr.......(3),

it does not work.

Comment: @KunalBatra Of course it works. I just showed an example... For it to work on `split` instead of `findall`, I removed some groups. Try the code the way I wrote in the example

Comment: pattern_string = r"(?:^.?|\n\s*|\s{7,})\(\d+\)"
pattern = re.compile(pattern_string)
with open("temp.txt", 'wb') as fff:
for match in pattern.finditer(text):
 fff.write(str(match.end()-1)+";")
        print str(match.end())+";"

The above is the code I am using. Does the pattern work fine with finditer?? Any changes to be made..

Comment: Can it  be done in the same exact way on finditer in the code I have just pasted..

Comment: @KunalBatra Why can't you just use split? `finditer` and `findall` might bring more pain... But, if you want... `r"(?:^|\n\s*|\s{7,})\(\d+\)"` (I fixed a error from copy/paste)

Comment: Hi Bernardo,Thankyou for the response. I am using the number of matches in a loop to store the broken data into separate files. So, using the finditer to return iteration objects which can be used in a loop.

Would the pattern you just pasted work with finditer as per the code I sent above.

Comment: Hi Bernardo,

Just to add, I found that for the case where thera are multiple spaces before a pattern e.g. ...(3), these spaces are actually \xc2\xa0\xc2\xa0\xc2\xa0\xc2\xa0 (3)

Actually all the spaces are in a similar pattern...

Will \s{7,} cover this pattern??

Appreciate a quick reply..

Comment: @KunalBatra `\s` is designed to handle any space char. Try using unicode strings (like `your_text.decode('utf-8')` ).